# Preserving variable in an observable life cycle

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

How can I preserve scriptId all over the observable lifecycle ?
If I try to run this code twice with different ids the sId var will change inside the observable and will break the code.

```
SendScript (event, scriptId) { 
    //THINGS HAPPEN...`enter code here`
    //Setting the id of the script
      let sId = scriptId; <------
    // This is changing every time i send the script
    // so later on in my observable this variable changing and breaking the 
    // uniqness of the script.
    //How can I do this correctly to use this id all the observable life and 
    //it completes ?
      this.scriptObs$ = from(scriptLinesObject)
        .pipe(
          concatMap((SL: ScriptLine) => {
            // more code here
            //I want to use the id here!   <------
            if(something) {
              return x;
            }
            else if(somethingElse) {
              return y;
            }
          }),
        ).subscribe(
          (res: any) => {
            // more code here
            //I want to use the id here! <------
          },
          (err) => { },
          () => { 
            // more code here
            //I want to use the id here! <------
           },
        );
    } 
  }
```

@Robert garcia

> If you need to maintain the variable give it a bigger scope, not a
>   local scope

what is the difference ? If i have a global var and I change it, my observable will still use the "Updated value" and not the "Starting value" (which I need).
please fix me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you need to maintain the variable give it a bigger scope, not a local scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to, `sId` value  already preserved in each `SendScript()` function call [thank to closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), the arrow function help you keep the context inside the Observable binded to the `SendScript()` function, so the `sId` value always be stored and scoped in each `SendScript()` function call :

```
SendScript (event, scriptId) { 
      ...
      let sId = scriptId;
      ...
      this.scriptObs$ = from(scriptLinesObject)
        .pipe(
          concatMap((SL: ScriptLine) => {
            console.log(sId)
            if(something) {
              return x;
            }
            else if(somethingElse) {
              return y;
            }
          }),catch
        ).subscribe(
          (x) => {
             console.log(sId)
          },
          (err) => { },
          () => { 
             console.log(sId)
           },
        );
    } 
  }
```

Additionally, since you using concatMap(), make sure the x and y returned within it is an Observable.